# MapReduce and similar methods to accelerate indexing of Apache Solr

Tags: solr, mapreduce, elasticsearch, elastic-map-reduce

I am building a web application in which users' content is indexed by Solr and then presented in a dashboard-type interface. Eventually, the requirements should allow users to upload a file of say 50 megs (some day 1 gig) and have their content indexed and ready to browse as soon as possible. Arbitrary benchmark: 1 minute. Preferred benchmark: 50 ms.

I am interested in methods to scale up the capacity of the Solr **indexing** operation. I have been reading up approaches of doing this [here](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/solr-hadoop-big-data-love), [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/scaling-solr-indexing), [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/03/indexing-files-via-solr-and-java-mapreduce/), [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/). It seems that AWS [elastic map reduce](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/), [elastic search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), and [SolrCloud](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud) are all potential approaches for solving this. I'm wondering whether there are accepted methods for scaling up indexing with on demand server resources, especially solutions that can be easily integrated into an existing AWS architecture.

Note, the application uses Solr 4.0.

Comment: Presentations from Lucene Revolution 2012 can be watched at this link, some relevant ideas in there. http://vimeo.com/album/2012139